# Change the video to play in AVPlayerViewController from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayerViewController that reproduces some video streams via URL and an UITableViewController that contains on its cells the urls that user can select to reproduce. When I click on any cell I call the function for change the stream to reproduce (setCanaleDaRiprodurre declared in AvPlayerViewController) passing the new stream url. The problem is that the function doesn't stop the player and doesn't change the stream to reproduce. Seems like I'am calling another instance of AvPlayerController and it isn't right, maybe i need a singleton instance ? 
I link the code of 2 classes and storyboard structure.

```
class VideoPlayerController: AVPlayerViewController {

//static let sharedInstance = VideoPlayerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://live1.msf.ticdn.it/Content/HLS/Live/Channel(CH01HA)/Stream(03)/index.m3u8") else { return }
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player?.play()
}

func setCanaleDaRiprodurre(url:String){

    let url1 = URL(string:url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url1!)
    player?.pause()
    player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    player?.play()
    print("Hello") 
}
```

Extract of table cell action:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let  VideoPlayerController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player") as! VideoPlayerController
    print(menuItems[indexPath.row].stream_url)
    print("sta andanndddooooo")
    VideoPlayerController.setCanaleDaRiprodurre(url: menuItems[indexPath.row].stream_url!)
    //VideoPlayerController.sharedInstance.setCanaleDaRiprodurre(url: menuItems[indexPath.row].stream_url!)

     }
```

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Noar8.png)

Comment: is your tableview in the same view controller? where does the video play? you should present a view controller or embed it as a child view controller. how are you doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are calling: `let  VideoPlayerController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player") as! VideoPlayerController` will create a NEW instance of the View Controller.

`AVPlayerViewController` acts pretty much in the same way as any view controller, it is generally full screen and presented as needed unless you embed it as a child view controller and add its view manually to another VC.

Either way, you need to maintain a single instance of the player view controller for this to work. If you can explain exactly what you are doing and what your trying to achieve I can provide an example of how to do it.